# How to enable onPress on children of Overlay component of React Native Elements library?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-elements

I am trying to trigger events using the onPress property in children of React Native Elements Overlay component. onPress property doesn't work i.e. nothing happens when I press on the component.

I have tried adding a zIndex attribute to the parent Overlay component and the children component with higher values given to children components and lower ones to parent Overlay component.

```
    <Overlay
      isVisible
      borderRadius={10}
      overlayStyle={styles.descriptionStyle}
    >
    <View style={styles.descriptionContent}>
      <MaterialIcons
        name="directions"
        size={48}
        color='#FFFFFF'
        />
      <LinearGradient
        colors={['#75cdd9', '#016f7e']}
        style={styles.createSessionButton}
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('CreateSession')}
      >
        <Text style={styles.createSessionButtonText}>Créer une sortie</Text>
      </LinearGradient>
    </View>
    </Overlay>
```

Expected result : Triggering navigation to 'CreateSession' component/screen by stack navigator.

Actual result : No event is triggered. Verified by implementing a console log in a call back function. Same problem and behaviour is encountered with the MaterialIcons component.

I am a beginner, so please be patient with me.

Answer (score 0):

In React Native you should wrap interactable components with `Touchable` since only some of basic components support `onPress` prop (such as Text and View). [react-native-linear-gradient](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient) doesn't support `onPress` prop, so you have to add `onPress` to `Text` component or to wrap your linear gradient into `Touchable`.

There is an example for `Text`:

```
<Overlay
  isVisible
  borderRadius={10}
  overlayStyle={styles.descriptionStyle}
>
  <View style={styles.descriptionContent}>
    <MaterialIcons
      name="directions"
      size={48}
      color='#FFFFFF'
      />
    <LinearGradient
      colors={['#75cdd9', '#016f7e']}
      style={styles.createSessionButton}
    >
      <Text
        style={styles.createSessionButtonText}
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('CreateSession')} // here
      >
        Créer une sortie
      </Text>
    </LinearGradient>
  </View>
</Overlay>
```

And for `LinearGradient`:

```
 <Overlay
  isVisible
  borderRadius={10}
  overlayStyle={styles.descriptionStyle}
>
  <View style={styles.descriptionContent}>
    <MaterialIcons
      name="directions"
      size={48}
      color='#FFFFFF'
      />
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('CreateSession')}> // here
      <LinearGradient
        colors={['#75cdd9', '#016f7e']}
        style={styles.createSessionButton}
      >
        <Text style={styles.createSessionButtonText}>Créer une sortie</Text>
      </LinearGradient>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
</Overlay>
```

More about `Touchable` components you could find in React Native [docs.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches)

Comment: Hello Georgiy, thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question. I applied the concept you suggested but it seems the Overlay component of React Native Elements seems to prevent interaction with its children. Even if I apply a higher zIndex value to children elements, the Overlay component prevents interaction like onPress events. But your suggestion helped me to implement onPress event on another component viz. Card of React Native Elements. I am upvoting your anwser because it helped me but it didn't solve the problem with the Overlay component. My vote is not displayed.

Comment: @Sujay it looks there was an issue for that: https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/issues/1713. Try to update `react-native-elements` dependency.

Comment: I had a look at this issue before asking the question on SO. I am already on version 1.1.0 which is the latest version of React Native Elements. I have checked in my package.json file.